# golang import package missing dependency package

Tags: go

I am trying to set up the project in https://github.com/liyiheng/qnmahjong, however, when I execute  `go build -o qnmahjong -ldflags "-X main.branch=git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD -X main.commit=git rev-parse HEAD"`

It gives me an error on package `github.com/spf13/viper`. I found that this package's dependency requires github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/printer but that package is no longer exist. How can I fix this problem? And this project does not have go.mod file. If I set GO111MODULE=on, there will be another problem of having no go.mod file.

I am trying to setup the project in https://github.com/liyiheng/qnmahjong
However, when I execute  `go build -o qnmahjong -ldflags "-X main.branch=git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD -X main.commit=git rev-parse HEAD"`

It gives me an error on package github.com\spf13\viper . I found that this package's dependency requires github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/printer but that package is no longer exist. How can I fix this problem? And this project does not have go.mod file. If I set GO111MODULE=on, there will be another problem of having no go.mod file.

Comment: `github.com/spf13/viper` contains a `go.mod` specifying the correct versions of all its dependencies, and works with modules. Make sure you have correctly setup your project's module.

Comment: You mean I need to create go.mod file in my project to explicitly indicate which version to call in the project?

Comment: Yes, you always need to use a module for dependency management, they are not optional when you want to work with external modules. See any of the official guides, like "How to Write Go Code".

Answer (score 1):

You could try running

```
go mod init github.com/liyiheng/qnmahjong
```

in the directory where the `main.go` lies. This will create the `go.mod` file and try to download the dependencies. Fix errors conitnuing from there.

Comment: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus@v1.9.3: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/sirupsen/logrus
                but was required as: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus

Don't have idea how to fix this.

Comment: @AnsonChan: that package was renamed 6 years ago, you need to update the references to use the correct module name of `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` (or specify all versions pf packages that are just as old and refer to the old path)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Go\src\qnmahjong\util\token.go:18:6: undefined: jwt.StandardClaims

I tried to modify the go.mod require version. But still it produces this error.

Comment: @AnsonChan the project you linked is quite old and left no record of its dependencies. It’s going to take some effort to try and reconstruct what all the dependencies were 6 years ago, if it’s even possible. Most likely you need to fork the project and update it to work with newer dependencies.

Comment: I finally fixed the dependencies in the go.mod  . But I have problem to execute  `docker build -t qnmahjong` . I have used `go.build -o`and generated qnmahjong . But don't know why it gives me ERROR: unable to prepare context: path "qnmahjong" not found